# Form Submit With A Preview

Tags: forms

I have a fairly long HTML form that the user fills out.  After filling it out, the user is given a preview of the data they are submitting.  From there they are able to commit the data into the system or go back and edit it.  I'm wondering what the best approach to handling this preview step is.  Some ideas I had are:

- Store the form data in a cookie for
  the preview
- Store the form data in a
  session
- Put the data in the DB, with
  a status column indicating it's a
  preview

What do you usually do when creating a preview like this?  Are there other issues to consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the data as hidden fields ().

Why not cookie or session?
 - If the user decide to discard this data, he may just navigate to other page. When he return later and see the data intact, he maybe surprised.

Why not database?
 - If the user just close the browser, who clean up the data in your db?  ... I would rather not write a cron job for this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the best-practise, but when I did this task, I've put it in a session. I expected the user to preview and submit/reedit the data during just single session so the session was enough for me.

If you want you preview to persist on your users machine you should use a cookie - that means the user doesn't have to sumbit/reedit the preview during single session, but can close the browser between this operations, and than return back to the preview in next session. Using this aproach, you have to consider that user can deny cookies in his browser. That's why people usually combine sessions with cookies together.

Putting the data in a database (with a status column) is not necessary unless you want to track and store the previews and edit operations somehow. You can imagine the database as a drawer in your table - you put there papers with whatever you want to store and find later. If you're just drawing a preview draft, and after the result is submitted, only a final version is stored in a drawer/database and the preview is crumpled and thrown away, than you won't put this in database. But if for some reason you think you will later go through the drafts, then they have to be stored in a database.

I'm not sure if it's clear with my english, but I did my best :D

Comment: Good point about the DB, it seems unnecessary to store the preview data there, unless I want to use it later.

Answer (score 0):

I'd gauge it based on how difficult the form was to fill out in the first place. If it's a lengthy process (like information for a mortgage or something) and you have user logins, you may want to provide them an opportunity to save the uncompleted form and come back to it later.

A session is only good for (depending on your setup) tasks that will take less than an hour. Manual input of data (like CD/DVD cataloging) that is easy to start and easy to finish will be perfect to store a session. Likewise, if the person has to stop and root around for some documents (again, in the case of a mortgage app, or an online tax form, etc.), you'll have a really irate person if the session times out and they have to retype information.

I'd avoid directly injecting content into a cookie, since the data is passed for subsequent requests and, assumedly, you already have access to basic session functionality.

If you go with a DB, you **will** need to timestamp the access (assuming you don't just leave it around with some saved name as determined by your user, like 'My 2008 Mortgage Documents') so you can clean it up later. If the user does save it mid-form, just leave it around until they complete the form or delete it.